# Updating ListView isn't working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I have an app that records sound. After the sound has been recorded, the user is asked (AlertDialog) to rename the recorded file. After the file was renamed, the name of the file is added to .txt document (stored in Android/data/package_name). In the second activity, there is a listview, items are added to listview from this .txt file. Now after you probably kind of know how my app works, here is the problem.

In the second activity, I added a OnLongClickListener. If a user long clicks an item in ListView, it opens a menu with an option "rename". After the user types in a new name and press OK, the name of the file is changed, as well as the name of the file inside that .txt file.

The problem is that the ListView isn't updated, so I need to restart the activity for it to be updated. I tried a lot of things and nothing works.

I tried a few different updateListView methods:

```
public void updateListView(){
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
    vg.invalidate();
}
```

And this one:

```
public void updateListView(){
    listAdapter.clear();
    listAdapter.addAll(recordedFilesArray);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I also tried calling listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on button click and basically everywhere I could think of and nothing works. The only way to see that the file was renamed is to restart the activity.

Restarting the activity on button click isn't possible because the activity is inside tab layout and if it is restarted, it automatically opens activity #1, while this is activity #2.

Implementing listAdapter:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.layout.simplerow, recordedFilesArray);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

recordedFilesArray is an ArrayList to which names are added from the .txt file

Comment: Can u please show your implementation of the listadapter

Comment: @Anuj updated my original post

Comment: I am assuming that `recordedFilesArray` is an array of strings which you populate by reading from your text file. Can you make sure that after the `rename` through long press your array actually contains the updated value? I know this might sound too obvious but just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update text in your source `Array` of `ListView`. So, if you have `ArrayList<String>` with items for your `ListView`, then update `String` in that array and call `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then problem is not here. But this works for me a great while.

Comment: That's exactčy what was the problem :) the element in ArrayList wasn't getting updated until the activity was restarted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try run your code in uithread maybe you are calling this function from another thread:

> runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void run() {
>       *your code of update here
> }
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the following error somewhere in your LogCat:

> E/AndroidRuntime(9026):
>   android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

then it means you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a background thread.

Note that `notifyDataSetChanged()` *must* be called from the UI thread.

You can do this by wrapping the call to it in a `Runnable` that you post to the UI thread like so:

```
YOURACTIVITY.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously replace YOURACTIVITY with a reference to your `Activity`.